# Django countries not show country list

Tags: python, django, django-countries

I have problem in Django countries. I install it (over pip), run makemigrations, run migrate, and added on my settings.py django-countries in INSTALLED_APPS

In model file i have:

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField
class Server(models.Model):
    country = CountryField()
```

But when i create new server in django admin, i see empty select. 
I read [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-countries) and [this](https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries), but this manuals do not give us anything new.

Please, tell me, what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Do you want a drop down for countries in admin page?

Comment: yes, i do input-select country list in admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug in the recent 3.0 release:
https://github.com/SmileyChris/django-countries/issues/81

Reverting to 2.1.2 worked for me.